# Теряется ссылка на один и тот же объект при сериализации-десериализации через DataContract

Tags: c#, .net, сериализация, десериализация

Пытаюсь сериализовать сложный объект через `DataContract`. Объект имеет список подобъектов, которые имеют в свою очередь свой список (назовем - листья дерева). К этим листьям, например, первого элемента списка основного объекта, можно добраться их других элементов списка (ссылка одна и та же). Получается довольно сложный граф, в котором много связей.

При десериализации у каждого элемента списка - свои листья, т.е. ссылки теряются, если в объекте источнике - это один и тот же лист, то после десериализации - просто копия.

Примерно так

```
    A                A
   / \              / \
  B   C    ====>   B   C
   \ /             |   |
    D              D   D[копия]
```

(это очень упрощенная схема)

Пробовал для всех классов прописать `DataContract(IsReference = true)`, так, на всякий случай - не помогло.

Есть ли более "быстрый" способ корректной десериализации, кроме как "ручное" выстраивание структуры повторяющей объект-источник?

Спасибо.

Comment: При создании `DataContractSerializer` задайте ему настройки `new DataContractSerializerSettings { PreserveObjectReferences = true }`.

Comment: Или можно использовать `NetDataContractSerializer`.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, ой, я в никах ошибся.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, оформите, пожалуйста, ответ. Помогло Ваше решение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При создании сериализатора задайте ему настройку `PreserveObjectReferences = true`.

```
var settings = new DataContractSerializerSettings { PreserveObjectReferences = true };
var dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(SomeType), settings);
```

Также можно использовать `NetDataContractSerializer`.